# get Media ID without using media picker in umbraco

Tags: pdf, razor, package, media, umbraco7

in umbraco back office media section , I have a folder named "**pdf**" and added some pdf files into that .

now in rendering , I have this array of Json s.  {["1010\pdf_sample10.pdf"]}

"1010" is "media folder *name* in the project" and the file in it. but ***I dont have the file ID*** , so how can I get the ID of media  in Umbraco just with this string "Path" ?

seems I cant use MediaPicker here

I need to limit user to pick just "pdf" in media folder and see just pdf s , thats because I couldn't find a way to use mediapicker .

this is the package I tried to use , but no sample found for that 
https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/file-picker-data-type/

```
var picker = CurrentPage.PdfPicker;
foreach (var item in picker)
{
  @item  //{["1010\\pdf_sample10.pdf"]}
}
```

Comment: You could use a Multinode Treepicker and limit it to Media items within your **pdf** folder.

Comment: I agree! MNTP would be perfect for this situation...

You could even create a Folder in the Media section specifically for PDF documents
and lock your MTNP down to that folder. That way, it limits what the user can see also in Media section.

Good luck Craig.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the problem is I dont want the user to see the files other than pdf in the folder. at the moment I have a PDF folder and I can limit them to choose only from that folder. but how if they put some non-pdf files into this folder ?